# how to pass the name of a method in a url

Tags: jakarta-ee

I want to know how to pass the name of the method to execute an action, this the code that I wrote in page.jsp

```
         <s:url id="url" action="FormInt!nom_of_method" includeContext="false"/>
    <s:a href="%{url}"><s:text name="Accueil.FormInt"/></s:a>
```

I will execute the method (nom_of_method) that is in action (FormInt),but it generated error with the following link

```
            http://localhost:7070/example/FormInt!nom_of_method.action
```

the link i want to have

```
  http://localhost:7070/example/FormInt.action
```

P.S: I use Struts2
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the method and action in the `<s:url/>`.
You can instead use:

```
 <s:url var="url" action="FormInt" method="nom_of_method" includeContext="false"/>
```

And since id is deprecated, Use `var` as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple actions inside of the same package, where each action can use the same class with different method invocation.

```
<package name="yourPackage" namespace="/myPackage" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="m1" class="com.stackoverflow.MyAction" method="methodOne">
        <result name="success">pages/action.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="m2" class="com.stackoverflow.MyAction" method="methodTwo">
        <result name="success">pages/anotherPage.jsp</result>
    </action>

  </package>
```

Now you can use any method in your view like this:

```
<s:url var="urlMethod1" action="m1" namespace="/myPackage" />
<s:url var="urlMethod2" action="m2" namespace="/myPackage" />

<s:a href="%{urlMethod1}">My url method 1</s:a>
<s:a href="%{urlMethod2}">My url method 2</s:a>
```

Where m1 is mapped to the myPackage/m1 based on your configuration of this package, and when you execute this url, you will invoke the method MyAction.methodOne of your action class, and for m2 will be the same, only points to MyAction.methodTwo.

Your action class will looks like this:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

public class MyAction{
    public String methodOne(){
        //your code here
        return "success";
    }

    public String methodTwo(){
        //your code here
        return "success";
    }
}
```

You can try this, I hope it helps you.